# How to handle errors in apache ant?

Tags: ant

I'm calling ant targets one after the other in sequence.  If one target fails I want to continue with the next target in the sequence.  How to do this?

Currently i call targets using ***antcall*** task.

FYI - Each target invokes java class using ***taskdef***.  This java class can throw exception.

Please suggest.

Note:- I cannot use any other third party jars like ant-contrib etc..

Comment: Ant has  `-keep-going` or  `-k` argument. It instructs the following targets that do not depend on failed targets.Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

> Currently i call targets using antcall task.

Don't use `antcall`. Build files aren't *programs*. They're dependency matrixes. You let Ant decide what targets to call and in what order. For example, I have a target called `package` which depends upon my code being compiled in target `compile`. That `compile` target depends upon my source code being generated in a target `generate-source`. My `build.xml` will look something like this:

```
<project default="package" name="my.proj">
    ...
    <target name="generate-source">
        ...
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="generate-source">
        ...
    </target>

    <target name="package" depends="compile">
        ...
    </target>
</project>
```

When I say:

```
$ ant package
```

Ant looks at my dependency matrix. It realizes that it needs to run the `compile` target before it can run `package`, and then realizes it needs to run `generate-source` before `compile`. Thus, Ant will automatically run the targets in this order:

- `generate-source`
- `compile`
- `package`

Note I didn't have to say that `package` was dependent upon the target `generate-source`. Instead, all I had to do was specify the primary dependencies, and Ant will work out the other subsequent dependencies by itself.

What's wrong about using `antcall` to force ordering? Because I may get it wrong. What if my `build.xml` changes? I now have to go through and verify my entire file looking to see if my `antcall` tasks are still correct. Also, in more complex build files, you can end up calling the same task over and over.

We had a developer write our `build.xml` files before I came. In one build, he divided the `build.xml` into multiple build files (another no-no) and then manually used `ant` and `antcall` tasks to do the build. The result were some targets being called up to 15 times in the build process and a build taking over 20 minutes to do as a particular target was called again and again (and each target would remove the artifacts generated by the previous call). A rewrite of the build file shortened the build process to a mere 4 minutes.

As a bonus, each target could be called and worked. For example, a developer could call the `compile` target without having to build the entire package -- something thats nice to be able to do when you are debugging your code. Also, don't do any clean process as part of the normal build steps. Instead, have a `clean` target that deletes all generated artifacts. Removing built artifacts as part of the normal build process can slow down debugging. If a developer requires a clean slate, they can run the `clean` target.

As an answer to your original query, Almost all tasks can be set to ignore errors and continue. I recommend to use *properties* that can be set to override default settings:

```
<property name="halt.on.error"  value="true"/>

<target name="compile" ...>
    <javac ...
       failonerror="${halt.on.error}"
       .../>
    ....
</target>
```

If I run:

```
$ ant
```

The build will halt on a compile error. However, if I ran:

```
$ ant -Dhalt.on.error="false"
```

This will override the setting of the `halt.on.error` property in the build file itself, and allow the program to continue even on compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to skip the target you can continue the task ignoring the failure.

For e.g for `taskdef` you can try including parameter `onerror="ignore"` for `javac` task you can include `failonerror="false"`